# php artisan migrate:install Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5, I m trying install migrate with following command

```
php artisan migarte:intsall
```

but, its showing a PDOException error with message `SQLSTATE[HY000] access denied for user '' @ 'localhost to database in 'laravel'` (Its MyDatabase Name) `in connector.php 47..`

I don't know, How to solve...

I have even configured accurate database details in `.env` and `/confg/databasee.php` files.

Comment: `databasee.php` or `database.php` ?

Comment: Where your database is running. In the same machine your are running the command? If your database is running on a virtual machine you have to execute the command in that machine. 

This happened to me sometimes. I have Laravel Homestead running on my computer, and i properly set the database credentials in .env file, but if i run the command in my mac terminal, it throws that exception. Obviously i have to run the command inside the VM to the command to work.

Answer (score -1):

It means you improperly set your configuration (username or password). If you are working on a local machine, you first should define the environment. First of all find out the name of your machine. For this you can use `die(gethostname());`. Paste what you've got to `app/bootstrap/start.php`line `28`. You should get line like: `'local' => ['YourMachineName']`. Now you can configure your database connection properties on `app/config/local/database.php`. If you are in production machine you can edit your db configuration settings in `app/config/database.php` file and also define default database driver in that file. Line containing `default` array key.

Comment: This question is tagged Laravel 5. All of the above is only relevant to Laravel 4. Environment detection no longer works as such, and cascading configuration files no longer work as you describe.